# php: or condition if not on device?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

```
<?php
    $iphone = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $ipad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');
    $android = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $webos = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"WebOS");
?>
```

If I'm on an iPhone $iphone == 1, right!
If I'm on an Android device $android == 1.

How can I query if I'm on none of those devices?

```
<?php if ( !$iphone || !$android || $webos ) { ?>
```

doesn't work! Because If I'm e.g. not on an iPhone $iphone doesn't return anything (not 0 or false)

How can I solve that?

Comment: Browser sniffing is not generally a good idea. The browser might spoof it, or it might not send any, or it might be a new browser that you don't know of yet. Better design your site to scale nicely - look into CSS3 media queries and such.

Comment: @tdammers: He might want to do that in order to e.g. redirect to a small-screen layout. You don't always need to make it airtight, and you don't always care about false negatives.

Comment: I'm using css3 mediaqueries. @Jon exactly what I'm doing!

Comment: @Jon: you can use media queries to include style sheets based on the actual device screen size. Far more reliable than browser sniffing. Now if you were to include links to the respective app stores for android and iOS, then I'd agree that browser sniffing might be the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really simple:

```
<?php if ( !$iphone && !$android && !$webos && !$ipad ) { ?>
```

I guess you had a mindblock.

Comment: Probably need to add "&& !$ipad" to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want && instead of ||

```
if ( !$iphone && !$android && !$webos && !$ipad ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This says if you are not on any of those devices do something.